# Style an (complex) SVG on react-native web

Tags: css, react-native, svg, react-native-web

I am trying to style a complex SVG (which is more like a map), with many sub-elements on react-native web.

What's the best solution to style all the child elements with a single css-like styling property?

Comment: This question is way too broad. If you still need help, share a link to the svg path itself in a codepen/codesandbox.